# Rails connecting to wrong port when rendering views

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently doing research on this error, but so far I've not been able to figure out the problem.

When I run mysqld to start the mysql server everything seems to run fine except for these two errors.

```
RSA private key file not found: /usr/local/var/mysql//private_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
RSA public key file not found: /usr/local/var/mysql//public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
```

Notice how the path has a double slash. I'm assuming that mysql generates these keys automagically and uses them because I've never created them manually myself.

However my rails app's server seems to run fine, and shows a success message for loading the view, the browser stays blank for about 1 minute before I get an error page. This is what the error page says:

```
Errno::ETIMEDOUT - Operation timed out - connect(2) for "localhost" port 35729
```

So it seems like Rails is trying to connect to the local mysql server through port 35729, except it's running on port 3306? I've explicitly set this port number in database.yml to no avail. There is more to the story than that, obviously and I'm currently trying to figure out what else is happening here.

Here is the database.local.yml that is referred to by database.yml

```
development:
adapter:  mysql2
database: somepages_dev
pool: 5
timeout:  5000
encoding: utf8
```

I am able to enter the mysql command line by type mysql. So it seems like rails is misconfigured somehow?

Also, I found that by switching to other rails projects the database to rails connection works fine. Also works fine when I make a new rails project.

When editing the database.locl.yml file here's what I've tried:
I've tried a few permutations so far, all of which return the same error. I tried using just the host. Then the host + port. Then just the sock path. Then the sock path + host + port. I restarted my rails server each time I made a change.

** Probably the most strange thing of all is that I can still run rake commands to edit the database. I can do rake db:drop && rake db:create && rake db:migrate && rake db:seed and it all runs smoothly.

It's only when trying to render views that the error pops up

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Can you post the database.yml ?

Comment: Ok, I've updated the question with the database.yml file.

Comment: Try setting `host: 127.0.0.1` and `port: 3306`. That sometimes coerces it into working. The socket method is often more reliable though if you know where your `mysql.sock` file is.

Comment: You could start by adding port: 3306 to that config

Comment: I've tried a few permutations so far, all of which return the same error. I tried using just the host. Then the host + port. Then just the sock path. Then the sock path + host + port. I restarted my rails server each time I made a change. No cigar.

Comment: At this point you may want to see if this affects other projects than the one you're working on. For example `rails new` and see if that brand new one is also messed up in the same way.

Comment: Making a new app works. Also another existing app I'm working on works.

Comment: I've just updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my using LiveReload.

{:live_reload_port=>35729}

only half of the app was activated. I had the desktop app running but not the browser counterpart working.